# Read dynamically the data base information to connect to a data base

Tags: oracle, vba, excel, odbc

If I use VBA in Excel to import data from a server, I wrote the following:

```
Sub ImportData(message_string, location, table_name, env_name)
If env_name = "Name" Then
    connstring = "OLEDB;Provider=MSDAORA.1;User ID=myID1;password= MyPass1;Data Source=server1"
Else
    connstring = "OLEDB;Provider=MSDAORA.1;User ID=myID2;password= MYPass2;Data Source=Server2"
End If

With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=connstring, _
        Destination:=Range(location), Sql:=message_string)
    .RefreshStyle = xlOverwriteCells
    .Refresh
    .Name = table_name


End With
End Sub
```

How can I read the data `myUserName`, `myPass` and `server1` or `server2`
in a Excel sheet?

For instance to put this information in cells A1, A2 and A3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, all you want to do is use data from a sheet in your connection string - You would do this just like you would create any other string.

It would look as follows:

```
Sub ImportData(message_string, location, table_name, env_name)

Dim connstring As String

Dim myUserName As String
Dim myPass As String
Dim server1 As String
Dim server2 As String

    myUserName = Sheets(1).Range("A1").Value
    myPass = Sheets(1).Range("A2").Value
    server1 = Sheets(1).Range("A3").Value
    server2 = Sheets(1).Range("A4").Value

    connstring = "OLEDB;Provider=MSDAORA.1;User ID=" & myUserName & ";password=" & myPass & ";Data Source="

    If env_name = "Name" Then
        connstring = connstring & server1
    Else
        connstring = connstring & server2
    End If

    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=connstring, _
            Destination:=Range(location), Sql:=message_string)
        .RefreshStyle = xlOverwriteCells
        .Refresh
        .Name = table_name
    End With

End Sub
```

I updated the code to make it as easily updateable as possible - Hope it all makes sense.